# CMake: How to make dependence on package optional?

Tags: cmake

I would like MPI to be optional for using my code.

I currently have a Cmake project that includes MPI as follows in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
```

My some of my .cpp and .h files have the following:

```
#define MPI_available true
```

On a system where MPI is not available, one can remove the first statement and change the second statement into `#define MPI_available false`. Then the code is structured such that it doesn't attempt to include ``mpi.h''. However, I would prefer CMAKE to detect the presence/absence of MPI, and set the MPI_available flag for compiling the source files accordingly.

I believe setting

```
find_package(MPI QUIET)
```

will ensure that cmake does not choke when it cannot find MPI. Is this the preferred way of getting where I want to be? If so, how to link this to the flag? If not, what should I do to make MPI optional when cmake-> making the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call to `find_package(someLib)` sets a variable `someLib_FOUND`. You can use it to check whether the someLib is available, then you can set a compile definitions. Something like:

```
find_package(MPI)
if(NOT MPI_FOUND)
   target_compile_definitions(yourTarget PUBLIC MPI_available=0)
endif()
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling cmake's default `FindMPI.cmake` module through `find_package(MPI)` already ensures that cmake will define the variable `MPI_FOUND` to reflect whether mpi was found or not.

Afterwards, you can use `MPI_FOUND` to achieve your goal.  For example, you can generate your project's `config.h` with calls to cmake's [`config_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html) to define macros such as `MPI_available`, and update your code accordingly.